# Unable to click a button which is associated with JQuery

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, htmlunit

Using HtmlUnit/Selenium I am unable to click the "Show More Products" div in the page http://www.myntra.com/men-tshirts . The click on the div in the real time browser is executing a JQuery in the background which is being loaded as part of http://myntra.myntassets.com/myx/javascripts/search.min.bb3ae82fb0f65d5447b1c9aed4afbd3eac8291b6.js along with the page and posting a new request to the server. I want to crawl images from this site. I have tried using Nutch, scrapy and crawler4j crawlers but they don't alone support button clicks. Can anyone help me to know how to handle this kind of clicks through code?? Or Other than HtmlUnit or Selenium is there any other api which can help me to click this kind of elements??

Here is the code that I have tried:

Selenium:

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("http://www.myntra.com/men-tshirts");
    WebElement loadMoreDiv = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Show More Products')]"));
    loadMoreDiv.click();

    (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
            WebElement divTags = d.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Show More Products')]"));
            if(divTags != null){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();
    System.out.println(pageSource);
    driver.quit();
```

HtmlUnit:

```
    WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    client.getOptions().setTimeout(30000);
    client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
    client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    client.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());

    HtmlPage page = client.getPage("http://www.myntra.com/men-tshirts");
    client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(30000); 
    System.out.println("******************* the page after loading is : \n" + page.asXml());        

    HtmlDivision loadMoreDiv = page.getFirstByXPath("//div[contains(text(), 'Show More Products')]");

    page = loadMoreDiv.click();

    client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(30000);

    System.out.println("******************* the page after the clicking is : \n" + page.asXml());
```

Solution :

Sorry!!! Actually there was some problem with my configuration. I was using old version of browser(firefox 27) and driver(FirefoxDriver 2.40.0). After updating them(FireFox 51.0.1 and FirefoxDriver 3.0.1) and adding the below lines to code allowed me to click the required div

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\myPath\\geckodriver.exe"); 
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox(); 
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true); 
WebDriver driver = new MarionetteDriver(capabilities);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your `XPath` as target button initially has no styles (`style=''`), but after first click `style="display: block;"` appended, so `"//div [@class='show-more'][@style='']"))` is not applicable anymore... Just try

```
WebElement loadMoreDiv = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='show-more']"))
```

or

```
WebElement loadMoreDiv = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Show More Products')]"))
```

**Update**

Above code works well in `Chrome`, but not in `Firefox`. If you still want to use `Firefox`, you could use following workaround:

```
WebElement loadMoreDiv = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Show More Products')]"))
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView;", loadMoreDiv);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body")).sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_UP)
loadMoreDiv.click()
```

Comment: Okay Let me try and let you know. Thanks !!

Comment: I have tried this:
`WebElement loadMoreDiv = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Show More Products')]"));`
and
`WebElement divTags = d.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Show More Products')]"));`
But still click is not working

Comment: What is output? Any exceptions?

Comment: I am not seeing any exceptions. The code is able to find the button. But I am seeing the same page after the click.

Comment: Oh... Yep, now I see. This seem to be `Firefox` issue, but code works well in `Chrome`. Let me know if it mandatory to use `Firefox`

Comment: Check updated answer. No it should work with `Firefox` also

Comment: Sorry! Actually there was some problem with my configuration.

I was using old version of browser(firefox 27) and driver(FirefoxDriver 2.40.0).

After updating them(FireFox 51.0.1 and FirefoxDriver 3.0.1) and adding the below lines to code allowed me to click the required div

 `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\myPath\\geckodriver.exe");

     
     DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

     capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);


     
WebDriver driver = new MarionetteDriver(capabilities); `

Answer (score 0):

I was able to click Show more products as many time as I wanted by changing xpath to cssSelector as follows:

```
WebElement loadMoreDiv = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.show-more"));
loadMoreDiv.click()
```